# Matlab function returning parent system of a subsystem?

Tags: matlab, simulink

In a simulink subsystem, I would like to replace all `From`-blocks by corresponding `In-/Outports` and a `From`-block in the parent system. Is there a MATLAB function which returns the parent system of a subsystem, or a convenient way to achieve this without tweaking path strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any block (including a subsystem), you can ask for the value of the parameter **Parent**,

```
>> get_param('model/ParentSystem/ChildSystem', 'Parent');

ans =

'model/ParentSystem'

>>
```